# A problem in sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Three numbers in AP are removed from first $n$ consecutive natural numbers and average of remaining numbers is found to be $\frac{43}{4}$. Find $n$ as well as removed numbers if one of the removed number is a perfect square.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the average of the first $n+3$ natural numbers?  Is $0$ a natural number?

Comment: I tried taking the n natural numbers but I always get one equation with two unknowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we let $k-d$, $k$, $k+d$ be the 3 terms in AP which are removed, then we are trying to find integer solutions to $$\dfrac{1}{n-3} \left( \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} - 3k \right) = \dfrac{43}{4}$$

We can conclude that $n \geq 18$, because if $n = 17$, the greatest average we could get would be to remove $1$, $2$, $3$, giving an average of $10.5 < 43/4$. And of course, if $n < 17$ the average would be even smaller. Similarly $n \leq 23$.

Now, in the above equation, since $n(n+1)/2 - 3k$ is an integer, and we need the denominator to be $4$, we must have that $n-3$ is divisible by $4$. This gives only two possible values: $n=19$ and $n=23$. Putting $n=23$ into our original equation gives $k = 61/3$, which is bogus. However, $n=19$ gives $k=6$. Restricting one of the terms removed to be a square, any of $d=2,3,5$ will work.

Comment: Note: I assumed the natural numbers were starting from 1, but even if we start from 0, we still get no solutions.

Comment: Sum of n natural numbers is (n)(n+1)/2.. Maybe you did a mistake by taking n(n-1)/2

Comment: @King good catch. In that case $n=19$ gives a solution - I will amend my answer